# Conexion PHP Mysql en servidor web con base de datos servidor externo

Tags: php, sql

La verdad que escribo esta pregunta aclarando que a pesar de tener experiencia programando PHP y mysql, me toca ahora hacer algo que no me habian pedido anteriormente, por lo cual necesito me puedan orientar acerca de que informacion buscar o leer para documentarme al respecto.

Tengo una web en su servidor para mostrar un catalogo en internet. Este catalogo se muestra con la base de datos de MySql a traves de PHP. Ahora necesitamos que en vez de actualizar la tabla de productos manualmente, por formulario o por phpmyadmin, esta tabla sea actualizada desde la data que se encuentra en el servidor de la empresa, cuyo programa administrativo corre en SQL.

El tema es que no se por donde empezar a documentarme, si es a traves de ODBC o se debe apuntar a una direccion http del servidor y descargar la data o si se puede hacer alreves, que el servidor envie la informacion a la web y actualice la tabla, etc. etc. Mucho sabria agradecer la orientacion al respecto. Gracias !

Comment: de lo que entiendo tu requerimiento, necesitas definir la arquitectura necesaria para extraer información de una base de datos SQL Server y esta sea integrada a MySql, adusco que en los dos gestores de bases de datos tienes tablas similares es decir una tabla de productos con el mismo nombre de campos. Para ello lo que te puedo sugerir es que el lenguaje que usas para tu aplicación web sea este (php, asp, java) generes unas aplicaciones de integración es como esto cuando se produzca una actualización en la base de datos Maestro (SqlServer), tu aplicativo de integración extraiga la data y la ac

Comment: Muchas gracias Christian, si algo asi estaba leyendo, tipo web service o una aplicacion de alguno de los lados que se conecte via mysql remoto por ejemplo. Voy a empezar a hacer pruebas y luego comento el resultado, efectivamente la base principal esta en el sistema administrativo, la esclava en la web y ambas tienen una tabla con la misma estructura.

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!